# How to specify custom conf file for Spark Standalone's master?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

Every time I start Spark Standalone's master, I have to change a different set of configs (`spark-env.sh`) depending on an application. As of now I edit `spark-env.sh` every time I need to overwrite/change any variable in it.

Is there a way so that while executing `sbin/start-master.sh` I could pass the conf file externally?

Comment: @summerbulb I am looking for custom config to Start the Master, not submitting job! spark-submit is used to submit the job (starting application). My concern is with starting the spark itself

Comment: Why would you be interested in starting and stopping spark over and over? I would expect spark to be running continuously.

Comment: This spark client is used to submit many applications and I allow multiple master from same node that's why

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `--properties-file` with the path to a custom **Spark properties** file. It defaults to `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`.

```
$ ./sbin/start-master.sh --help
Usage: ./sbin/start-master.sh [options]

Options:
  -i HOST, --ip HOST     Hostname to listen on (deprecated, please use --host or -h)
  -h HOST, --host HOST   Hostname to listen on
  -p PORT, --port PORT   Port to listen on (default: 7077)
  --webui-port PORT      Port for web UI (default: 8080)
  --properties-file FILE Path to a custom Spark properties file.
                         Default is conf/spark-defaults.conf.
```

If however you want to set environment variables, you'd have to set them as you'd do with any other command-line application, e.g.

```
SPARK_LOG_DIR=here-my-value ./sbin/start-master.sh
```

---

One idea would be to use `SPARK_CONF_DIR` environment variable to point to a custom directory with the required configuration.

From [sbin/spark-daemon.sh](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sbin/spark-daemon.sh#L24) (that is executed as part of `start-master.sh`):

> SPARK_CONF_DIR  Alternate conf dir. Default is ${SPARK_HOME}/conf.

So, use `SPARK_CONF_DIR` and save the custom configuration under `conf`.

I've just noticed `spark-daemon.sh` script accepts `--config <conf-dir>` so it looks like you can use `--config` not `SPARK_CONF_DIR` env var.

Comment: I am now using your suggestion and running command $SPARK_CONF_DIR=/home/customConfigLocation/ ./sbin/start-master.sh      I have placed customized spark-config.sh inside customConfirLocation. Similar command I am using to start slave. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not much clear exactly are you looking to configure the spark program or just configure to pass the right parameter in a shell script. If it is shell script probably this is not the right place however for setting the config file on spark is quite tricky this is based on how and where you run your spark program. If your are client mode then you can set the config file locally and pass into your program based on your spark program(scala, python, java) but in cluster mode, it can't access the local file.

If you are looking just to pass the config parameter into the spark program you can try as below example

```
spark-submit \ 
--driver-java-options "-XX:PermSize=1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=3072M" \ 
--driver-memory 3G  \ 
--class com.program.classname \ 
--master yarn \ 
--deploy-mode cluster \ 
--proxy-user hdfs \ 
--executor-memory 5G \ 
--executor-cores 3 \ 
--num-executors 6 \ 
--conf spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2 \ 
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2900 \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \ 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=10 \ 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=20 \ 
--conf spark.speculation=false \ 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=6 \ 
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=6 \ 
 
--conf spark.network.timeout=10000000 \ 
--conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=10000000 \ 
--conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=4048 \ 
--conf spark.driver.cores=3 \ 
--conf spark.shuffle.memoryFraction=0.5 \ 
--conf spark.storage.memoryFraction=0.5 \ 
--conf spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout=300  \ 
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \ 
--conf spark.shuffle.service.port=7337 \ 
--queue spark \
```

Comment: There are 2 parts , 1st Starting spark itself with configuration, 2nd Submitting job with master with conf. Your solution is for later part while I am trying to seek someway to pass conf while starting the Spark.